# faktory: error=redis not booted, cannot start Unable to boot the command server

Tags: python, redis

I've installed faktory using homebrew and also using pip (python3.7).  I've also installed honcho and when I run honcho, I got this problem:

`14:41:40 faktory.1 | E 2019-11-06T19:41:40.697Z error=redis not booted, cannot start Unable to boot the command server`

Could any help?

Basically, I followed the tutorial from here: https://www.mikeperham.com/2019/01/08/using-faktory-with-python/

This is my f.client.py:

```
# fclient.py
import faktory
import random
import time

time.sleep(1)

with faktory.connection() as client:
    while True:
        client.queue('adder', args=(random.randint(0,1000), random.randint(0,1000)))
        time.sleep(1)
```

This is my fworker.py:

```
# fclient.py
import faktory
import random
import time

time.sleep(1)

with faktory.connection() as client:
    while True:
        client.queue('adder', args=(random.randint(0,1000), random.randint(0,1000)))
        time.sleep(1)
```

and then this is my Procfile:

```
redis: redis-server
faktory: faktory
client: python3 fclient.py
worker: python3 fworker.py
```

Instead of using ruby's foreman like in the link, I decided to use honcho library for python.  Within the same directory as those files, I typed `honcho start` and this is what is shown in my screen:

```
12:06:28 system    | redis.1 started (pid=1175)
12:06:28 system    | client.1 started (pid=1176)
12:06:28 system    | faktory.1 started (pid=1177)
12:06:28 system    | worker.1 started (pid=1178)
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:C 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.034 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:C 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.034 # Redis version=5.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1175, just started
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:C 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.034 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.036 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.039 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.039 # Server initialized
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.039 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.039 * Ready to accept connections
12:06:28 faktory.1 | Faktory 1.1.0
12:06:28 faktory.1 | Copyright © 2019 Contributed Systems LLC
12:06:28 faktory.1 | Licensed under the GNU Public License 3.0
12:06:28 faktory.1 | I 2019-11-07T17:06:28.050Z Initializing redis storage at /Users/me/.faktory/db, socket /Users/me/.faktory/db/redis.sock
12:06:28 faktory.1 | E 2019-11-07T17:06:28.052Z error=redis not booted, cannot start Unable to boot the command server
12:06:28 system    | faktory.1 stopped (rc=0)
12:06:28 system    | sending SIGTERM to redis.1 (pid 1175)
12:06:28 system    | sending SIGTERM to client.1 (pid 1176)
12:06:28 system    | sending SIGTERM to worker.1 (pid 1178)
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:signal-handler (1573146388) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
12:06:28 system    | client.1 stopped (rc=-15)
12:06:28 system    | worker.1 stopped (rc=-15)
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.144 # User requested shutdown...
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.144 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.146 * DB saved on disk
12:06:28 redis.1   | 1175:M 07 Nov 2019 12:06:28.146 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
12:06:28 system    | redis.1 stopped (rc=0)
```

Comment: Can you show us [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I put up the code.